# How to Compare CGAffinetransform?

Tags: ios, xcode

How Will I complete this code I'm having errors.

```
-(IBAction)dropDownBtn:(id)sender {

 dropDownBtn.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(720*M_PI/360);

if ([dropDownBtn.transform CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(720*M_PI/360)) {

    dropDownBtn.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(520*M_PI/360);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 30):

There is a function to compare transforms:

```
CGAffineTransformEqualToTransform(transform1, transform2)
```

Answer (score 2):

In Swift you use the equal to operator (==)

```
transform1 == transform2
```

Comment: Hove you tried it before posting? Have you added Equatable extension? :P

Comment: @JulianKról yes you can see this declared by default in the core graphics header `public func ==(lhs: CGAffineTransform, rhs: CGAffineTransform) -> Bool`. Just cmd+click on the == operator. Maybe just swift 3? Haven't tried it with earlier versions.

Answer (score 1):

If you need equality testing with given accuracy (useful in unit tests) I use this function:

```
BOOL CGAffineTransformEqualToTransformWithAccuracy (CGAffineTransform firstTransform, CGAffineTransform secondTransform, CGFloat epsilon) {
    return (fabs(firstTransform.a - secondTransform.a) <= epsilon) &&
            (fabs(firstTransform.b - secondTransform.b) <= epsilon) &&
            (fabs(firstTransform.c - secondTransform.c) <= epsilon) &&
            (fabs(firstTransform.d - secondTransform.d) <= epsilon) &&
            (fabs(firstTransform.tx - secondTransform.tx) <= epsilon) &&
            (fabs(firstTransform.ty - secondTransform.ty) <= epsilon);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an extension:

```
import CoreGraphics

extension CGAffineTransform: Equatable {}

public func ==(lhs: CGAffineTransform, rhs: CGAffineTransform) -> Bool {
    return CGAffineTransformEqualToTransform(lhs, rhs)
}
```